# directional-aware hover breaks on overflow scroll

Tags: jquery, css, 3d

I have a directional aware hover effect I've set up.  It works fine until I place it in a container with overflow scroll.  When it first loads and you haven't scrolled at all it works fine, but as soon as you start scrolling the parent container the rollover always acts like you've rolled in from the top and I can't figure out why.

I have a fiddle of this problem set up, this is very confusing and I'd love any help I can get on this:

http://jsfiddle.net/loriensleafs/nfYD6/

this is the specific js for the directional awareness:

```
$(".container").bind("mouseenter mouseleave",function(e){

/** the width and height of the current div **/
var w = $(this).width();
var h = $(this).height();

/** calculate the x and y to get an angle to the center of the div from that x and y. **/
/** gets the x value relative to the center of the DIV and "normalize" it **/
var x = (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft - (w/2)) * ( w > h ? (h/w) : 1 );
var y = (e.pageY - this.offsetTop  - (h/2)) * ( h > w ? (w/h) : 1 );

/** the angle and the direction from where the mouse came in/went out clockwise (TRBL=0123);**/
/** first calculate the angle of the point, 
 add 180 deg to get rid of the negative values
 divide by 90 to get the quadrant
 add 3 and do a modulo by 4  to shift the quadrants to a proper clockwise TRBL (top/right/bottom/left) **/
var direction = Math.round((((Math.atan2(y, x) * (180 / Math.PI)) + 180 ) / 90 ) + 3 )  % 4;


/** do your animations here **/ 
switch(direction) {
 case 0:
  /** animations from the TOP **/
        currentSides = "thumb_cube show-top";
 break;
 case 1:
  /** animations from the RIGHT **/
        currentSides = "thumb_cube show-right";
 break;
 case 2:
  /** animations from the BOTTOM **/
        currentSides = "thumb_cube show-bottom";
 break;
 case 3:
  /** animations from the LEFT **/
        currentSides = "thumb_cube show-left";
 break;
}});
```

Comment: The fiddle isn't complete: it misses many non-webkit properties in its CSS, so it can really only be viewed in Chrome. You should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 0):

the problem here was in the directional awareness script.

```
var x = (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft - (w/2)) * ( w > h ? (h/w) : 1 );
var y = (e.pageY - this.offsetTop  - (h/2)) * ( h > w ? (w/h) : 1 );
```

because of the use of html offset the measurements are wrong, its the offset of the document not the browser window which is what it needs to be.

The solution here was to use the jquery offset, so the code changes to:

```
var x = (e.pageX - $(this).offset().left - (w/2)) * ( w > h ? (h/w) : 1 );
var y = (e.pageY - $(this).offset().top  - (h/2)) * ( h > w ? (w/h) : 1 );
```

This takes the offset measurement from the browser window.

Comment: Can you also accept your own answer by clicking on the checkmark? That way, this question will not show up on the list of unsolved ones.